# "INSERT into" not working

Tags: php, mysql

Query "INSERT into" not working, and doesn't returns error. (All code works correctly, but the query doesn't work)

```
public static function setActivity($activity, $id_user, $extra)
{
    switch($activity)
    {
        case 'inscriptionRaffle':
            // inscriptionRaffle $extra = ID SORTEO
            $query = db::query('SELECT * FROM '.TABLE_RAFFLES.' WHERE id = "'.db::escape($extra).'"');
            $array = db::fetch_assoc($query);
            $en_title = 'Has been enrolled in the raffle of <a href="?module=raffles&id='.$array['id'].'">'.$array['name'].'</a>';
            $es_title = 'Se ha inscrito en el sorteo de <a href="?module=raffles&id='.$array['id'].'">'.$array['name'].'</a>';
            db::query('INSERT INTO '.TABLE_ACTIVITY.' (id_user, es_title, en_title, date) VALUES ("'.$id_user.'","'.$es_title.'","'.$en_title.'","'.time().'")');
            break;
        case 'register':
            break;
    }
}
```

Constant:

```
define('TABLE_ACTIVITY',    TABLE_PREFIX . 'users_activity');
```

Table:

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and print out the query string, after variable substitution.  The answer will probably be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

`date` is an `int(11)` as per your schema, but you are enclosing it in quotes `"'.time().'"` in the query.

Change its datatype to `datetime` or `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the pre-defined data-type of `DATETIME` for your `date` field ? Alter your table and change the date field to `DATETIME`.

And I don't think there is any function defined as `time()` in any `SQL` language unless you have defined yourself.

So your query should be like this:

```
db::query('INSERT INTO '.TABLE_ACTIVITY.' (id_user, es_title, en_title, date) VALUES ("'.$id_user.'","'.$es_title.'","'.$en_title.'","'.NOW().'")');
```

`NOW()` is a pre-defined function to retrieve the current `date and time` if you are using `MYSQL`.

If you are using `MSSQL` then you need to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

Comment: The `time()` function is being not called in SQL. That part is fine. Also, `now()` IS a MySQL function, and you're calling it in PHP.

Comment: Dude, while inserting any datetime, there is `now()` function in mysql, but what if u want to insert datetime from the form itself when hitting the submit button ?? What will u use at that time ??

Comment: Yes there is. But, you are using it in PHP.  `...,"'.$es_title.'","'.$en_title.'", NOW())');` would mean that `NOW()` is being called in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, it works

`db::query('INSERT INTO '.TABLE_ACTIVITY.' set id_user="'.$id_user.'",es_title="'.$es_title.'",en_title="'.$en_title.'",date="'.NOW().'"');`